# "No route matches" error but only on new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a form where the model has a nested resource (an image uploaded with Carrierwave), and in the nested resource I have a link_to that allows the deletion of the image.  Clicking the link removes the carrierwave item and deletes the image.  This all works perfectly for the edit function, but when trying to go to the new screen I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"listings", :action=>"remove_image"} 
(ActionView::Template::Error)
```

Here is the link in question:

```
    <%= link_to "Delete this image", remove_image_path(builder.object.id), 
        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this image?", 
        :method => :delete %>
```

here is my routes entry:

```
match "/remove_image/:id" => "listings#remove_image", :as => "remove_image"
```

And here's the method from the ListingsController:

```
def remove_image
  @image = SecondaryImage.find(params[:id])
  @listing = Listing.find(@image.listing_id)
  @image.remove_image
  @image.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to edit_listing_path(@listing), 
                notice: "Successfully deleted secondary image" }
  end 
end
```

**UPDATE: Rake routes**
As requested, here are the routes related to the ListingsController

```
   listing_secondary_images GET    /listings/:listing_id/secondary_images(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"secondary_images"}
                            POST   /listings/:listing_id/secondary_images(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"secondary_images"}
new_listing_secondary_image GET    /listings/:listing_id/secondary_images/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"secondary_images"}
edit_listing_secondary_image GET    /listings/:listing_id/secondary_images/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"secondary_images"}
 listing_secondary_image GET    /listings/:listing_id/secondary_images/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"secondary_images"}
                         PUT    /listings/:listing_id/secondary_images/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"secondary_images"}
                         DELETE /listings/:listing_id/secondary_images/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"secondary_images"}
                listings GET    /listings(.:format)                                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"listings"}
                         POST   /listings(.:format)                                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"listings"}
             new_listing GET    /listings/new(.:format)                                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"listings"}
            edit_listing GET    /listings/:id/edit(.:format)                              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"listings"}
                 listing GET    /listings/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"listings"}
                         PUT    /listings/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"listings"}
                         DELETE /listings/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"listings"}
                features GET    /features(.:format)                                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"features"}
                         POST   /features(.:format)                                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"features"}
             new_feature GET    /features/new(.:format)                                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"features"}
            edit_feature GET    /features/:id/edit(.:format)                              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"features"}
                 feature GET    /features/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"features"}
                         PUT    /features/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"features"}
                         DELETE /features/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"features"}
                  orders GET    /orders(.:format)                                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"orders"}
                         POST   /orders(.:format)                                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"orders"}
               new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"orders"}
              edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                                {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"orders"}
                   order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                                     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
                         PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                                     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"orders"}
                         DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                                     {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"orders"}
         preview_listing GET    /preview/:id(.:format)                                    {:controller=>"listings", :action=>"preview"}
         approve_listing        /approve/:id(.:format)                                    {:controller=>"listings", :action=>"approve"}
            remove_image        /remove_image/:id(.:format)                               {:controller=>"listings", :action=>"remove_image"}
```

Comment: Could you post a rake:routes?

Comment: I've update the post with my routes.  Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply doing this?

```
<%= link_to "Delete this image", "/remove_image/#{builder.object.id}", 
    :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this image?", 
    :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work!  Could you tell me what changing the link to does behind the scenes that this works and that remove_image_path method doesn't?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure, but I'm glad it worked! If it's what you're after, would you accept my answer? Thanks :)